# Unwanted padding around buttons in dialog

Tags: android, button, layout, dialog, padding

**The Problem:**

[image: Unwanted Padding]

You can clearly see the padding around the button

**The Code:**

```
public void startGameDialog(){

    Context context = GameBoardActivity.this;

    ContextThemeWrapper ctw = new ContextThemeWrapper(context, R.style.AppBaseTheme);

    AlertDialog.Builder startGameDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(ctw);
    startGameDialog.setTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.whats_your_name));

    LinearLayout dialogLayout = new LinearLayout(context);

        LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

        dialogLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

        final EditText newName = new EditText(context);
        newName.setLayoutParams(params);

        newName.setText("");

        final Button submit = new Button(context);
        submit.setText(getString(R.string.done));
        submit.setLayoutParams(params);

    dialogLayout.addView(newName);
    dialogLayout.addView(submit);

    startGameDialog.setView(dialogLayout);
    final Dialog dialog = startGameDialog.create();

    OnClickListener onClick = new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            GameBoardActivity.NAME = newName.getText().toString();
            dialog.dismiss();
            setUpPlayers();

        }
    };
    submit.setOnClickListener(onClick);     

    dialog.show();
    dialog.setCancelable(false);        

}
```

**Attempted solutions** (Both failed):

1. Using the builder `.create()` method to build to `AlertDialog` and setting `.setView(dialogLayout, 0, 0, 0, 0)`.
2. Removing parent's padding by trying `ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) dialogLayout.getParent()` then trying `parent.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);` (This returned a `NullPointerException` error because you can't set padding for `Dialog` nor `AlertDialog`.

Any other ideas!?

Thanks in advance!

JRad the Bad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Default Button in android has a natural padding. You can remove it by either changing the background or the style on the layout XML.

Comment: Than can you share the layout XML for that pop-up dialog?

Comment: I'm going to double confirm this but I believe this is incorrect.

Comment: There is no XML for it. Everything you see in the dialog is generated via the Java above.

Comment: Then you can use  submit.setBackground(context.getResources().getDrawable(R.id.YOUR_DRAWABLE));

Comment: I understand that. I don't want to use a custom drawable. I'm trying to use the built in buttons. They look good.

Comment: Then you can just imitate it using a 9 patch. since as far as I know default button also uses a 9 patch resources with padding which is why the button generated will always have a natural padding. There's always an option you can use. :)

Comment: And FYI, you can see your resources in \sdk\platforms\android-19\data\res\drawable-xxhdpi. See for yourself what I'm talking about. :)

Comment: @JRadtheBad This answer is correct. It's not actual padding, it's transparent pixels in the background bitmap. See for example `btn_default_normal_holo_dark.9.png`. You should provide a new background if you want it different -- but be mindful that you'll probably need the selected, disabled, &c variants too.

Comment: @matiash in general terms it is still a padding hahaha! Well thanks for the support. And yes, that's the drawbacks of creating your own resources. :)

Comment: @JRadtheBad PS. If targeting Android 4.3, you could possibly use `layoutMode=opticalBounds` (see [this](http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.3.html#OpticalBounds)) to "remove" the padding without changing the drawables (that's what the red lines are for). But unfortunately it won't work on previous versions.

Comment: Yeah, I've been looking into the 9 Patch concept for android. It seems to me that there should be a simple way to increase the button size then and allow natural clipping to remove the padding. Creating all the extra patch 9 variants seems like a lot of excess work for something so trivial... :/

Comment: @Matiash, just saw your comment regarding `opticalBounds`. I'll look into that, thanks.

Comment: BWahahahaha... I found a solution around this without changing the 9 Patch images: I added it as a second solution below...

Answer (score 0):

Set minimum Hight & minimum width to "0" then padding will remove for ex

```
submit.setMinHeight(0);
```

Answer (score 0):

So I figured another solution:
Keep in mind, this could break things if the 9 Patch images in the SDK get changed in the future, but otherwise, it works seemlessly to remove the 9Patch images' padding and works with all API's. 
Here's the code I changed:

```
    //set to compensate for 9 patch padding on button
    dialogLayout.setPadding(-5, 5, -5, -8);
    //set to compensate for dialogLayout padding affecting the EditText view
    FrameLayout editTextWrapper = new FrameLayout(context);
    editTextWrapper.addView(newName);
    editTextWrapper.setPadding(5, 0, 5, 0);

    dialogLayout.addView(editTextWrapper);
    dialogLayout.addView(submit);
```

Comment: Warning: Those hard-coded values (in pixels) will be off in devices with a different density than the one you're testing on. You'll probably want to fix `dp` values instead, and convert them to pixels in runtime.

Comment: Haha, well told you there's a lot of options though I won't recommend it just like what @matiash says. take note that those resources are in 9 patch images with px padding that stretches out depending on the screen density. :p